# How can hide and show HTML fields depends on the value of the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have the following checkbox:

```
<!-- Choose betweeen Upload a video and Insert a video link -->
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="control-label">Link video</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="link_video"
        value="0"
        class="switch checkbox-action"
    />
</div>
```

By default the value is false, that is, I want to allow users to upload a video, that is, I want to have the following code:

```
<!-- Upload a video -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <p>
            Put the video here
        </p>
        {!! Form::hidden('temp_video_filename') !!}
        <input-dropzone
            name="video-dropzone"
            label="Dropzone"
            url="/admin/object/upload-video"
            :config="{
                clickable:true,
                chunking:true,
                chunkSize: 250000,
                parallelUploads: 1,
                uploadMultiple: false,
                maxFilesize: 1000,
                maxFiles: 1,
                acceptedFiles: '.mov, .mp4'
            }"
            @click="initVideoUpload()"
            @drop="initVideoUpload()"
            @upload="videoUploaded($event)"
        />
    </div>
    @if($a->video_id)
    <div class="col-md-12 uploaded-videos">
        <a href="{{ $a->getDirectPlayUrl() }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary download">
            <i class="fa fa-play"></i> View video
        </a>

        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-delete remove" data-record="File" data-url="{{ $a->getAdminVideoRemoveApiUrl() }}" data-callback-function="A.removedAdminVideo">
            <icon-delete color="var(--on-error)"></icon-delete> Remove file
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

However, if the user click on the checkbox, that is, the value is true I would like to show the following field:

```
    <!-- Insert video link -->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::field('video_embed_url', ['label' => __('labels.link_video')]) !!}
        </div>
        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::label(__('labels.preview')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is to appear additionally, you can use jQuery and onClick event.
Try this code for checkbox:

```
<!-- Choose betweeen Upload a video and Insert a video link -->
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" 
      class="form-check-input switch checkbox-action"
      id="link_video"
      name="link_video"
      value="0"
      onclick="$('#extraField').toggle();"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="link_video">Link video</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for field:

```
<!-- Insert video link -->
<div class="row mb-3" id="extraField" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      {!! Form::field('video_embed_url', ['label' => __('labels.link_video')]) !!}
  </div>
  <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      {!! Form::label(__('labels.preview')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using Bootstrap, see also: [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/)